# How to display image in custom cell to detail view

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *__strong)indexPath
{


    TestViewController*detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestView"];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated: YES];

    detail.outputLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:[mutablearray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      // detail.outputImage.image =[NSString stringWithFormat:[mutablearray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];  
}
@end
```

Using above code i displayed text in tableview cell to detail view.

I also want to display image corresponding to each row in detail view. Problem lies in the commented part i know.

What modification is needed?

when uncomment i got the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteData getCharacters:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: This usually comes when u have over released an object. Check if the contents of mutableArray2 are intact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `outputImage` is an UIImageView object.
I seems you are setting `NSString` object instead of `UIImage` object. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

**First**
I believe you should move the  `[NSString stringWithFormat:[mutablearray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];` above your Push command.

**Second**
I don't understand the relation between your question title and it's content.

**BTW Third**
You are using -

```
    [NSString stringWithFormat:[mutablearray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

not appropriately.

You will use  `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` when you want to manipulate a string -

```
  NSString * str1 = @"hellow";
  str1 = [NSString string with format:@"str1 %@",world];
```

When the %@ will be replaced by the word after the comma. (there is more to it, but i wanted to give you a basic idea).

If you simply want to pass a word you should simply (I assume your array contains strings!):

```
   detail.outputLabel.text =[[mutablearray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: fine explanation.I move  detail.outputLabel.text =[[mutablearray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; above push command. But then detail view   is showing empty.

Comment: figure it out. code:[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated: YES];
    
    
    detail.outputLabel.text =[mutablearray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.outputImage.image=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[mutablearay2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];